# On input focus change parent class in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to toggle a class on the parent of the input field when you click in it or focus on it. I'm facing two issues. First, why is my onFocus called on render without me even clicking inside the field? Second, do I need a separate isActive state for each input field or is there a better approach? I Asked because potentially my form could have many more input fields. And I would need a state to capture value for each anyways. Does this mean I need two states per input?

```
export default class ContactForm extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      isActive: false
  }

  onFocus(e) {
    console.log(e);
    // setState for each input field here.
  }

  render() {
    return (
        <div className="contact-form">
          <h2>Contact Form</h2>
          <form>
            <div className={isActive ? 'textfield is-focused': 'textfield'}>
              <label htmlFor="inputName">Name</label>
              <input type="text" 
                     id="inputName 
                     ref="_name" 
                     onFocus={this.onFocus('name')} 
              />
            </div>
            <div className={isActive ? 'textfield is-focused': 'textfield'}>
              <label htmlFor="inputEmail">Email</label>
              <input type="email" 
                     id="inputEmail" 
                     ref="_email" 
                     onFocus={this.onFocus('email')} />
            </div>
            <input type="submit" value="send message" />
          </form>
        </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: hi @user3376065, I think this could help https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/handling-events.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your second question first, it's rendering right away because you need to bind the method to `this` - so your code would look like this.

```
<input type="text" 
                 id="inputName 
                 ref="_name" 
                 onFocus={this.onFocus('name').bind(this)} 
          />
```

Alternatively, you could put it in your constructor, which is generally cleaner.

```
export default class ContactForm extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      isActive: false
  }

  this.onFocus = this.onFocus.bind(this);
}
```

To answer your first question, yes, the way you have it setup now, you'd have to have a separate boolean for each input. There are better ways to do it, just try using css.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:focus

Comment: This is great, I'm assuming for setting state, I need to do something like a switch statement and look at the event.target.id to see which event the onFocus was called from then set that isActive to true but also set all the rest to false to make sure the class is toggled for the rest being out of focus? I have to say it is still a lot of work for a few fields.

Comment: Really, what you want to do is use css here, otherwise yes, you're creating too much work for yourself. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:focus

I edited my original answer because I think this is what you should use.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, if you don't want to call onFocus on render:

```
onFocus={() => this.onFocus('email')}
```